# remove column from grdiview

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

i want to remove this column from gridview i try to add values in dropdownlist in grdiview but when i add it works fine but this column in black color appears...
 how i remove it..

grdiview html

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="DocType" HeaderText="Document" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="DepType" HeaderText="Department" />

                   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ApproveID" DataField="ApproveID" 
             ></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# 
        Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" />

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server"
           class="vpb_dropdown">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


               </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure AutoGenerateColumns="false" is set on your GridView, and then delete the lines

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ApproveID" DataField="ApproveID"></asp:BoundField>
```

from your HTML. When you turn off AutoGenerateColumns, you will need to add each column manually.